# Number theory: Which (n,k) pairs satisfy the equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find $$(n,k)$$ ( n,k are positive integers ) pairs that satisfy the following equation:
$$n^k-1=(n-1)!$$

I found this question in a discrete math test book in number theory section and tried solving it using Wilson's theorem:

$$(p-1)!+1$$ is divisible by n if and only if p is a prime number.

Using this theorem we can say that if n is a prime number then the remainder of $n^k-1$ divided by n equals the remainder of $(n-1)!$ divided by n but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all natural numbers $n$ and $m$ for which $n^m=(n-1)!+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120369/find-all-natural-numbers-n-and-m-for-which-nm-n-11). I find the hint in the comments quite useful.

Comment: Yes . Thank you that was very helpful @player3236

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805068/to-find-all-n-such-that-n-11-is-a-perfect-power-of-n/805202#805202